# Prevent IntelliJ from keeping line breaks when reformatting binary expressions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, line-breaks, code-formatting, word-wrap

I have Java code that looks like this in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1:

```java
int x = (3 + 4 + 5 + 6) *
    (7 + 8 + 9 + 10) *
    (11 + 12 + 13 + 14 +
        0xFFFFFFFF);
```

When I run **Code > Reformat Code**, I would like it to unwrap and look like this:

```java
int x = (3 + 4 + 5 + 6) * (7 + 8 + 9 + 10) * (11 + 12 + 13 + 14 + 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

Under **File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Keep when reformatting**, I have **Line breaks** unchecked, as seen here:

[image: Line breaks: unchecked]

I also have **Binary expressions** set to **Wrap if long**:

[image: Binary expressions: Wrap if long]

Despite this, the above code is not modified when reformatted. Is there a setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1. I filed a [bug report and it has since been fixed in build 146.907](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153329).